# Changing typescript decorator dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a field in a typescript class which has a decorator A, but i want change the decorator from A to B when it is running in some specific environment.
Can this be achieved in typescript?

```
class SampleClass {
    @DecoratorA 
    sampleField;

    constructor() {
      if(condition) {
        // change DecoratorA to DecoratorB
      }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the DecoratorA to DecoratorB in the constructor based on some condition?

Comment: You could add decorator that changes behavior according to environment

Comment: Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that explains your problem. This is likely XY problem. As suggested above, this could be solved in a different way.

Comment: The decorators are from a third-party library @AlekseyL.

Comment: @PavanBahuguni You need to create a wrapper decorator that will apply one of them depending on the environment.

Answer (score 7):

So as suggested in comments create a [decorator factory](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories):

```
function AorB() {
    return condition ? DecoratorA : DecoratorB;
}
```

And apply it (pay attention to parentheses):

```
class SampleClass {
    @AorB() 
    sampleField;
}
```