# Dynamic list of decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, plugins, decorator

I would like to prepare very adjustable components using decorators (aka plugin system).
I found the great solution with [decorator factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561851/5612076), but I see that factory function returns a single decorator.

Example from the link above:

```js
function AorB() {
    // returns only one decorator
    return condition ? DecoratorA : DecoratorB;
}
```

```js
class SampleClass {
    @AorB() 
    sampleField;
}
```

What I want:

```js
function Plugin() {
    // returns any count of decorators
    return [
       @DecoratorA,
       @DecoratorB,
       //...
    ]
}
```

```js
// Something like this
...@Plugin()
class SampleClass {
    sampleField;
}
```

Are there some ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, you cannot directly return an array of decorators from a decorator factory. But, you can achieve similar thing by creating a custom decorator that takes an array of decorator functions and applies them sequentially like this

```js
function DecoratorA(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    console.log('DecoratorA applied to:', propertyKey);
}

function DecoratorB(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    console.log('DecoratorB applied to:', propertyKey);
}

function Plugin(decorators: Function[]) {
    return function (target: any) {
        for (const decorator of decorators) {
            decorator(target.prototype, 'sampleField');
        }
    }
}

@Plugin([DecoratorA, DecoratorB])
class SampleClass {
    sampleField: string;
}

const instance = new SampleClass();
```

please note that this approach applies decorators sequentially, and the order in which you pass the decorator functions to `Plugin` is important

Comment: This looks very much like a chat GPT answer to me.